# Rails : How to update current user profile with omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, service-provider

I am implementing an omniauth system with a **service provider** (SAML Protocol) that **does not provide user mail**.

My app is build with rails and Devise for authentication. **Emails are required** for all account creations. So with the service provider **registration will fail**.

To get around this, I was thinking :

1. The user could **create a regular accoun**t (password + email)
2. Then he could **"authenticate himself officially"** so that we could get the informations we need from the service provider.

In this way his profile will be complete.

**Do you think it's possible to do omniauth on an already active session and update the current user?**

If I do not use the current session I have no way to make the link between my service provider and the already existing account.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a different approach. When a user registers using omniauth without an email, I create a fake email and register the user using this email. The email I create lets the application know that it is not a real email and reminds the user to change it. Anyway, he can keep login in through oauth, but he can also change the fake email later.

After first registration the app goes to UsersController.finish_signup where the user can change or complete the email and other relevant information needed for a complete profile.

If a user is already registered (using a normal registration with email), he can then link his account to many oauth registrations.

**This is the code in User model** (a user has_many :identities):

```
def self.find_for_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource = nil)

  # Get the identity or create it if it does not exist
  identity = Identity.find_for_oauth(auth)

  user = signed_in_resource ? signed_in_resource : identity.user

  # Create the user if needed (if no logged in user and the identity has no user associated)
  if user.nil?

    # Get the existing user by email if the provider gives us an email.
    # If no email was provided we assign a temporary email and ask the
    # user to verify it on the next step via UsersController.finish_signup
    # email_is_verified = auth.info.email && (auth.info.verified || auth.info.verified_email)
    email = auth.info.email
    user = User.find_by(:email => email) if email

    email ||= "#{TEMP_EMAIL_PREFIX}-#{auth.uid}-#{auth.provider}.com"
    username = auth.info.nickname ? auth.info.nickname : 
         ( auth.extra.raw_info.nickname ? auth.extra.raw_info.nickname : 
         ( auth.extra.raw_info.username ? auth.extra.raw_info.username : "nickname: " + auth.uid) )

    # Create the user if it's a new registration.
    # Use default values that will be updated later
    if user.nil?
      user = User.new(
        name: auth.extra.raw_info.name,
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
      )
      user.skip_confirmation!
      user.save!
    end
  end

  # Associate the identity with the user if needed
  if identity.user != user
    identity.user = user
    identity.save!
  end
  user
end
```

**ADDED missing Identity model**

```
class Identity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :uid, :provider
  validates_uniqueness_of :uid, :scope => :provider

  def self.find_for_oauth(auth)
    identity = find_or_create_by(uid: "nickname: " + auth.uid, provider: auth.provider)

    identity.name = auth.extra.raw_info.name
    identity.email = auth.info.email
    identity.image_url = auth.info.image
    identity.profile_url = nil
    identity.token = auth.credentials.token
    identity.secret = auth.credentials.secret
    identity.save
    identity
  end
end
```